# How can I tweak windows authentication between known parties?

Tags: c#, wcf, iis, windows-authentication

I have a couple of `WCF` services  which communicate via *https* and use *windows authentication*. The applications are currently hosted over `IIS`.

I cannot change the authentication mode as for now - So using something else isn't an option.

Now, almost on every request I see the negotiation process occur again an again.

My questions are:

1. Is there any way I can prevent the "2 step" negotiation? I know that the service I'm going to call is going to challenge me. Is there any way I can send the Negotiation token on my first call and prevent an extra call?
2. Is there any way I can expand the frequency of this happening? Is there any TTL I can change here?